# document.getElementById('id') problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

folks,

I have on my pages (http://playdota.thilisar.cz) a JavaScript file(code below), that has to have an effect of modyfying the edge of the icons(for real, it has to load new picture) and loading the information(only plain text so far) into a div with ID "info" on mouseover event;on mouseout event it has to load the original picture to same position. But it only writes informations and replaces icons with "[object Object]" text.

I hope, you understand this, because my english isn't very good.

Thanks for your answers.

```
function showInfo(id){                     //Using jQuery 1.7.2
  document.getElementById('ses').innerHTML=$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "sentinel_str/"+id+"-info.html"
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#info").html(data)
    })
    $("#ses").find("li").mouseover(function(){
        $id=$(this).find("img").attr("id")
        $(self.document[$id].src='look/icons/'+$id+'_hover.jpg')
    })
    $("#ses").find("li").mouseout(function(){
        $id=$(this).find("img").attr("id")
        $(self.document[$id].src='look/icons/'+$id+'.jpg')
    })
})};
```

## CLOSED THANKS TO CHEESEWARLOCK'S ANSWER

### Thanks all, who tried to help me.

---

Comment: Well, if you're using jQuery why not take full advantage of it?

Comment: So you want to show the id information on MouseOver and load the image back on miouse out right?

Comment: Is needed to full advantage jQuery?

Comment: Do you have any background working with code like this, or did you just find some code somewhere and glue it together?  Really the code doesn't make any sense as it stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting `[object Object]` because you're setting the contents of an HTML element to a `jQuery` object. If you want to call a piece of jQuery code, you don't need to wrap it in `$()`. You can just call the code directly. So get rid of this line:

```
document.getElementById('ses').innerHTML=$(function(){
```

and this line:

```
})
```

and the rest of your code will be executed when you call `showInfo(id)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the innerHTML of the element to the value of the return of the jquery object.  In effect you're saying put the 'toString' value of this function as the content of the HTML.

Do you mean to have?  Unless I'm reading it wrong.
document.getElementById('ses').innerHTML=$(function(){

Answer (score 0):

The "mouseover" and "mouseout" handlers look pretty confused to me. There's no need to call `getElementById()` at all; you're using jQuery, and you can find the `<img>` tags with it. Once you've found them, you've found them; no need to find them again.

```
$("#ses").find("li").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find('img').prop('src', function() {
      return 'look/icons/' + this.id + '_hover.jpg';
    });
})
$("#ses").find("li").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).find('img').prop('src', function() {
      return 'look/icons/' + this.id + '.jpg';
    });
})
```

Passing a function as the second argument of `.prop` lets you compute the value of the property using the DOM element state directly.

Also you might want to use "mouseenter" and "mouseleave", which are sanitized by jQuery and are a little more reliable than "mouseover" and "mouseout".

*edit* — wow I just "zoomed out" and noticed that all this code is being set up as an `innerHTML` value, which makes no sense. Looks like a case of rampant copy/paste or something.

Answer (score 0):

The code written below would solve your problem and is even short. Check it out once.

```
var id;
$('#ses').find('li').each(function(){
   $(this).mouseover(function(){
    var image=$(this).find('img');
      id=$(this).find('img').attr('id');
     $('#id').hide();
$(this).append('<div>'+id+'</div>');
});
$(this).mouseout(function(){
$(this).html('');
$('#id').show();
});

});
```

Comment: Maybe it works, I must only edit some thing because it's doing nothing

Comment: I guess if the above is not working then I must have had a typo but this is actually a solution within one function itself.